# Not able to TRIM trailing space in varchar column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using oracle 11g DB and in one of the table having varchar column has data which has trailing spaces. I have tried TRIM function to update the column but still the space at the end of the string prevails. What can be the reason for the trailing space? and how to fix this issue.

Column contents are displayed as below.

```
select '<'||mycol||'>' from mytab
Output : <mysamplestring >

select DUMP(mycol) from mytab
Output : Typ=1 Len=28: 67,114,117,100,101,32,80,101,116,114,111,108,101,117,109,32,69,120,116,114,97,99,116,105,111,110,194,160
```

Thanks

Comment: Trim should work. Show  the real query.

Comment: update query that I used : update mytab set mycol=TRIM(mycol);

Comment: Try with `select '<'||your_coloumn||'>'` or `DUMP(your_column)` to see full content

Comment: Please run `DUMP(mycol, 1016) `. Character 160 seems to be a [Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) which is not removed by `TRIM`

Comment: Another stupid question: did you commit the changes you made with TRIM?

Comment: The 160 on the end is interesting too. The first 26 characters look normal ('Crude Petroleum Extraction') but you have those two odd chars on the end.

Answer (score 4):

Using UNISTR did the trick for me. It removed the characters 160 and 194

```
update mytab set mycol = REPLACE(mycol,unistr('\00A0'),'')
```

Comment: this removes all spaces, not leading and trailing.

Answer (score 0):

trim() should work as expected! Sure it is a `varchar2` column not a `char` column?

```
update hr.countries t
set    t.country_name = t.country_name || '   ';

update hr.countries t
set t.country_name = trim(t.country_name);
```

Comment: Yes its a varchar2 column and TRIM is not working :(

Comment: Seems like `chr(160)` does not get trimmed as mentioned in comments above. `update hr.countries t set    t.country_name = t.country_name || '   '||chr(160);` Trim will not trim this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the column type from char to varchar2, char column blank-pads the value with spaces to fill up the size of the field. So for a char(10) column, when you insert 'abc', it will automatically be inserted as 'abc       '

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I used DUMP and I found that spaces are char(160) and it will not get trimmed.
So what I did was `TRIM(BOTH chr(160) FROM COLUMNNAME)`
Documentation available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rreftrimfunc.html)